# Itering through a list if identical elements

Tags: python, list, pandas, iteration

I have the following function, which returns the pandas series of States - Associated Counties

```
def answer():
    census_df.set_index(['STNAME', 'CTYNAME'])
    for name, state, cname in zip(census_df['STNAME'], census_df['STATE'], census_df['CTYNAME']):
        print(name, state, cname)

Alabama 1 Tallapoosa County
Alabama 1 Tuscaloosa County
Alabama 1 Walker County
Alabama 1 Washington County
Alabama 1 Wilcox County
Alabama 1 Winston County
Alaska 2 Alaska
Alaska 2 Aleutians East Borough
Alaska 2 Aleutians West Census Area
Alaska 2 Anchorage Municipality
Alaska 2 Bethel Census Area
Alaska 2 Bristol Bay Borough
Alaska 2 Denali Borough
Alaska 2 Dillingham Census Area
Alaska 2 Fairbanks North Star Borough
```

I would like to know the state with the most counties in it. I can iterate through each state like this:

```
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
for name, state, cname in zip(census_df['STNAME'], census_df['STATE'], census_df['CTYNAME']):
     if state == 1:
         counter += 1
 print(counter)
     if state == 1:
         counter2 += 1
 print(counter2)
```

and so on. I can range the number of states (`rng = range(1, 56)`) and iterate through it, but creating 56 lists is a nightmare. Is there an easier way if doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas allows us to do such operations without loops/iterating:

```
In [21]: df.STNAME.value_counts()
Out[21]:
Alaska     9
Alabama    6
Name: STNAME, dtype: int64

In [24]: df.STNAME.value_counts().head(1)
Out[24]:
Alaska    9
Name: STNAME, dtype: int64
```

or

```
In [18]: df.groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME'].count()
Out[18]:
STNAME
Alabama    6
Alaska     9
Name: CTYNAME, dtype: int64

In [19]: df.groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME'].count().idxmax()
Out[19]: 'Alaska'
```

Comment: I see you had done this assignment as well :) thanks